# How to define a type: infinite function?

Tags: scala, language-lawyer

How to define a type `InfiniteFunction`, which is a function and when called returns another `InfiniteFunction`

The type looks like:

```
() => () => () => ... // infinite
```

or recursive:

```
type InfiniteFunction = () => InfiniteFunction
```

And this doesn't work

```
scala> type InfiniteFunction = () => InfiniteFunction
<console>:11: error: illegal cyclic reference involving type InfiniteFunction
       type InfiniteFunction = () => InfiniteFunction
```

### Problem

I want to do cps transform on this function:

```
def travel(tree: TreeNode): Unit = {
  if (tree != null) {
    travel(tree.left)
    println(tree.value)
    travel(tree.right)
  }
}
```

after cps:

```
def r[T](f: => T): () => T = () => f
def travel(tree: TreeNode, cb: () => AnyRef): Unit = {
  if (tree != null) {
    travel(tree.left, r{
      println(tree.value)
      travel(tree.right, cb)
    })
  } else {
    cb()
  }
}
```

Then I want to optimize the tail call by yielding them out, instead calling them:

```
def r[T](f: => T): () => T = () => f
def travel(tree: TreeNode, cb: () => InfiniteFunction): InfiniteFunction = {
  if (tree != null) {
    r(travel(tree.left, r{
      println(tree.value)
      r(travel(tree.right, cb))
    }))
  } else {
    r(cb())
  }
}

// demonstration how to use travel
var f: InfiniteFunction = r(
  travel(tree, r(throw new RuntimeException("it is over")))
)
// this will end by the exception "it is over"
while (true) f = f()
```

Here the type `InfiniteFunction` is needed, w/o the `InfiniteFunction` type, type conversion is needed:

```
def r[T](f: => T): () => T = () => f
def travel(tree: TreeNode, cb: () => AnyRef): () => AnyRef = {
  if (tree != null) {
    r(travel(tree.left, r {
      println(tree.value)
      r(travel(tree.right, cb))
    }))
  } else {
    r(cb())
  }
}

var f: () => AnyRef = r(
  travel(tree, r(throw new RuntimeException("it is over")))
)
while (true) f = f().asInstanceOf[() => AnyRef]
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to invent the Monad )

Comment: @Nyavro Great idea, I'll try implement using monad primitives.

Comment: @Nyavro when using monad, it becomes `Future` and for-syntax, by writing my `Future` class, the fully execution can be controlled by `Future.lift`, but it is a totally different story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a trait instead of a type alias to resolve the problem with the cyclic reference:

```
trait Inf extends (Unit => Inf)
```

Also `Unit` is the type of `()`

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem. Scala can't recognize `Unit => Inf` as a instance of `Inf`

Comment: It works, I got it by redefine `r` as `def r(f: => Inf): Inf = new Inf { def apply(x: Unit) = f }`

Comment: You can add an implicit conversion from `Unit => Inf` to `Inf` then.